# New Server is randomly adding port 7081 on HTTPS requests

Tags: php, https, nginx

I just installed a new LAMP server running NGINX on the backside. While it does not occur every time - certain HTTPS requests are seeking port 7081 in the URL. For example:

- http://www.nacdbenefits.com appears fine
- clicking the contact us redirects to https just fine
- clicking the link at the bottom right of the page (My Admin) shows a port 7081 and in turn causes errors once logged into the page.

Is this expected behavior from NGINX? I believe it is almost certainly related to NGINX because disabling it (and running off apache only) does not create this error.

### NGINX conf

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

### site vhost nginx conf

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.


server {
    listen 216.70.86.230:443 ssl;

    server_name nacdbenefits.com;
    server_name www.nacdbenefits.com;
    server_name ipv4.nacdbenefits.com;

    ssl_certificate             /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-rcx4WK;
    ssl_certificate_key         /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-rcx4WK;
    ssl_client_certificate      /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-Wj9EsP;
    ssl_session_timeout         5m;

    ssl_protocols               SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:7081;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias      /var/www/vhosts/nacdbenefits.com/httpdocs/;
        access_log /var/www/vhosts/nacdbenefits.com/statistics/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log;
        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
        internal;
    }
}



server {
    listen 216.70.86.230:80;

    server_name nacdbenefits.com;
    server_name www.nacdbenefits.com;
    server_name ipv4.nacdbenefits.com;


    client_max_body_size 128m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias      /var/www/vhosts/nacdbenefits.com/httpdocs/;
        access_log /var/www/vhosts/nacdbenefits.com/statistics/logs/proxy_access_log;
        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
        internal;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 1

I think it must have something to do with switching directories in HTTPS. Any pages will exist on the same domain level (such as the contact us page) do not cause this error. However, once a https connection is made from a sub directory (for sample the admin site), the Port 7081 takes place (which is the newly reconfigured ssl port for Apache since NGINX took over the 443 port).

### UPDATE 2

Using Firebug - I noticed that my server seems to be applying an automatic 301 redirect. Note: I do not have this in my current .htaccess file so not sure where it is coming from:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 22:27:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 314
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.nacdbenefits.com:7081/myadmin/
```

### UPDATE 3

I have noticed that if the trailing slash is added to the actual link, the issue does not occur anymore. It is almost as if NGINX is taking the requested URI, attempting to access the directory as a file and it passes it off to Apache which causes the 301 redirect. Adding a trailing slash eliminates this but is not exactly the solution I am hoping for. Surely there is a configuration within NGINX to resolve this.

Comment: Unless your php code has '7081' in it somewhere, it's likely to be something at the webserver level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers provided so far are targeted towards NGINX configuration, which makes them valid answers, however I have found that the actual problem for *Plesk* v11 servers (i.e. which is the situation in this particular case), lies in a misconfiguration with *Apache* on *Plesk* servers

To date Plesk have not provided a fix, however they do offer some workarounds:

http://kb.parallels.com/en/114425

Please note that the article linked to has references to PHP code but the problem also applies more generally at an Apache level.  Apache by default will tend to redirect folders, e.g. /test  to it's "correct" url equivalent, e.g. /test/  however it is this redirection that is failing due to Apache running on ports 7080 and 7081 on Plesk v11 servers, and Apache not being configured to handle these scenarios.

Comment: That link appears to have been removed now. More info on this here. https://talk.plesk.com/threads/security-attack-surface-ports-7080-and-7081.368543/. The suggested solution is to enforce apache to only listen on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is

```
https://www.nacdbenefits.com/myadmin
```

Redirects to:

```
https://www.nacdbenefits.com:7081/myadmin/
```

So, you must look at www.nacdbenefits.com:443 for /myadmin/ (is this your nginx server?) to see what is causing this redirect.

I'm guessing there is a .htaccess or other file which causes the redirect to the new url.

If you want to find out what is hosting on that port, use

```
lsof -i tcp:443
```

This will show if this is the Apache or nginx server. You posted the nginx init script, not the nginx config file.

Hopefully that gives you something to go on!

Comment: Note for others reading - there are no .htaccess redirects here so still something going on redirecting it to port 7081 instead of 443

Comment: I think the big question is - why is it redirecting to the 7081 (apache ssl port) instead of the nginx ssl port (443)? Is there a real way to find this out? Visiting the ports directly, I can definitely see from lsof -i tcp: when connections are made to the specific ports.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `nginx.conf`, and more specifically to the `upstream { }` declaration.

The *random* behavior suggests a load balancing configuration.

---

**edit**

According to the configuration, you are not using the load balancing via `upstream`, but

```
  proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:7081;
```

making the `https` requests are redirected to the port `7081` via `proxy_pass`. Maybe this line comes from a sample configuration found on the Internet?

Removing the `proxy_pass` and `proxy_set...` lines should fix the redirection.

Comment: posted but I do not seem to find the upstream { } declaration.

Comment: you posted the nginx start script not the conf file that is in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: sorry about that - changes updated

Comment: @JM4 The answer is edited: the problem comes from `proxy_pass`.

Comment: @ring0 - It is how the server is default configured on Plesk 11 and Media Temple. Port 7081 is the Apache SSL port after NGINX is added. If NGINX is disabled this defaults to 443 as expected. Please see my last update 3 - it is something related to directory and trailing slashes as well.

 Having been forced to migrate to a new server has pretty much been a nightmare with all the bugs I've had to correct. I am hoping I notice some benefits soon because all the talk of nginx and some of the other feature enhancements have yet to be realized.

Comment: @JM4 `nginx` is great and if your server is busy you will likely to notice benefits, memory and speed wise.

Comment: Note - I cannot modify the default config file as you state however because it will be overwritten each time the service or server is restarted without major configuration changes to Plesk. I think the issue is elsewhere given the trailing slash discovery.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your configuration. IT will help if you describe your architecture and post nginx and apache configs.

https://www.nacdbenefits.com:7081/ is definitely accessible publicly so you do have something running on that port.

Comment: conf files posted

Answer (score 0):

As redirects returned by your backend server doesn't match what's written in your `proxy_pass`, default `proxy_redirect` doesn't work for you and you have to configure `proxy_redirect` yourself.  The following should do the trick:

```
proxy_redirect  https://www.nacdbenefits.com:7081/  /;
```

See [docs](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) for details.

Comment: Where would I set this? As noted above, I **cannot** edit the actual vhost nginx conf file (the last file listed) - it is built my plesk and regenerated by default each time nginx is reloaded. Also - is there a way to do this on a system wide level as opposed to domain by domain? I have this issue with over 30 websites currently.

Comment: Ideally, it should be set in the location with the proxy_pass directive in question.  Though you may try to configure proxy_redirect's for all your hosts at http{} level, it should work as long as it's not redefined at server/location level.  You may also try to use variables/regular expressions in proxy_redirect (as supported in nginx 1.1.11+) to configure some generic pattern like `proxy_redirect https://$host:$proxy_port/ /;`.